# Access parent object from Controller extension of Apex-based custom list view button

Tags: apex, custom-button

Imagine you want to add a custom button (Apex based, no JS) to the Related Contacts list on an Account detail page. To perform the buttons action you need some information of the parent Account.

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactAction_CtrlExt"   
           recordSetVar="contacts" action="{!doAction}">

</apex:page>
```

**Controller class**

```
public with sharing class ContactAction_CtrlExt {

    private Account account;
    private List<Contact> relatedContacts;


    // CONSTRUCTOR

    public ContactAction_CtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController) {
        account = ...???...;
        relatedContacts = (List<Contact>) standardSetController.getRecords();
    }


    // ACTION METHOD

    public PageReference doAction() {
        doSomething(account, relatedContacts);
    }   
}
```

**Is there a way to access the account in the Controller Extension code of your list button?**

Comment: Do you have a custom visualforce page on the standard account layout or is it a custom button on the stanrad related list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get the ID parameter of the page:

```
public ContactAction_CtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController) {
    String accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    account = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Id = :accId]:

    relatedContacts = (List<Contact>) standardSetController.getRecords();
}
```

Here is a simple example. I've created a list view button on the Contact object with Content Source "Visualforce Page". On that page i access the ID parameter:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" tabStyle="Account" recordSetVar="">
    Id: {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}
</apex:page>
```

This this exact the Account ID:

[image]

Comment: what i saw was standard controller is on contact

Comment: @mastOr: As Mohit states the button is not embedded directly on the account page. I am using this technique: http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/

Comment: @RobertSösemann So is it a List View button??

Comment: Yes. As the title states ;)

Comment: @RobertSösemann So try my solution then. It must work, this only looks so tricky  but if you access the ID through ` ApexPages` you will get the ID of the Account :)

Comment: Never expected this to work. But it does!! ;)

Comment: @mast0r Serious .Even never thought it will work and works .Awesome.Really tricky